# sync data from mobile app to DB and show it on web page

Tags: php, android, mysql, web, synchronization

I developed an Android-App and now I want to sync the data from the app to a database.

The solution i found was to use [volley](https://google.github.io/volley/) to post a request to php script, which also handles the db communications. Is there a better solution to sync the data safely?

Also, I want the synced data to be displayed on my website, to let each user check and modify their data on the website as well. Could you point me in the direction of any good solution for this?

I already tried using a CMS for the website like Wordpress and Joomla, but could not connect this to another database based on username.

Comment: Currently your request for _any_ good suggestion, of a platform to show data on a website based on users, is a bit too broad for Stack Overflow. I empathize that it is difficult to find something and make a choice but [here is not the place](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to start a discussion about this.

Comment: "Better" in what way exactly? What problem is your current approach giving you that you need to solve?